# Why are there layout discrepancies between the Design preview in Android Studio and the rendered UI in the Android emulator?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I have several layout-related questions concerning the screenshots below.

My version of Android Studio runs on OS X Yosemite. Here are version details:

[image: About Android Studio]

Here is the screenshot of the layout in the Design tab of Android Studio:

[image]

Here is the screenshot of the rendered UI in the Android Emulator:

[image]

Here is the actual XML file for the activity layout:

> ```
> <LinearLayout
>     android:orientation="horizontal"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_gravity="top"
>     android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
>     android:layout_marginRight="5sp">
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:orientation="vertical"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_weight="0.5"
>         android:layout_marginRight="5sp">
>         <TextView
>             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:text="@string/company"
>             android:gravity="center"
>             android:textSize="@dimen/label_font_size" />
>         <EditText
>             android:id="@+id/company"
>             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:inputType="text"
>             android:textStyle="bold"
>             android:textSize="@dimen/entry_font_size"
>             android:gravity="center"/>
>     </LinearLayout>
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:orientation="vertical"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_weight="0.5"
>         android:layout_marginLeft="5sp">
>         <TextView
>             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:text="@string/team"
>             android:gravity="center"
>             android:textSize="@dimen/label_font_size" />
>         <EditText
>             android:id="@+id/team"
>             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:inputType="text"
>             android:textStyle="bold"
>             android:textSize="@dimen/entry_font_size"
>             android:gravity="center"/>
>     </LinearLayout>
> </LinearLayout>
>
> <LinearLayout
>     android:orientation="vertical"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_gravity="top"
>     android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
>     android:layout_marginRight="5sp">
>     <TextView
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="@string/web_service"
>         android:gravity="center"
>         android:textSize="@dimen/label_font_size" />
>     <EditText
>         android:id="@+id/web_service"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:inputType="text"
>         android:textStyle="bold"
>         android:textSize="@dimen/entry_font_size"
>         android:gravity="center"/>
> </LinearLayout>
>
> <LinearLayout
>     android:orientation="horizontal"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_gravity="top"
>     android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
>     android:layout_marginRight="5sp">
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:orientation="vertical"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_weight="0.5"
>         android:layout_marginRight="5sp">
>         <TextView
>             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:text="@string/service_start"
>             android:textSize="@dimen/label_font_size"
>             android:gravity="center"
>             />
>         <TimePicker
>             android:id="@+id/service_start"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:timePickerMode="spinner"/>
>     </LinearLayout>
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:orientation="vertical"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_weight="0.5"
>         android:layout_marginLeft="5sp">
>         <TextView
>             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:text="@string/service_end"
>             android:textSize="@dimen/label_font_size"
>             android:gravity="center"
>             />
>         <TimePicker
>             android:id="@+id/service_end"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:timePickerMode="spinner"/>
>     </LinearLayout>
> </LinearLayout>
>
> <LinearLayout
>     android:orientation="vertical"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_gravity="top"
>     android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
>     android:layout_marginRight="5sp">
>     <TextView
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_gravity="top"
>         android:text="@string/subscriber_id"
>         android:gravity="center"
>         android:textSize="@dimen/label_font_size" />
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:orientation="horizontal"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_gravity="top"
>         android:weightSum="100">
>         <EditText
>             android:id="@+id/subscriber_id_1of4"
>             android:layout_width="0dp"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_gravity="top"
>             android:layout_weight="45"
>             android:inputType="text"
>             android:textStyle="bold"
>             android:textSize="@dimen/entry_font_size"
>             android:gravity="center"/>
>         <TextView
>             android:layout_width="0dp"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_gravity="top"
>             android:layout_weight="10"
>             android:text="-"
>             android:gravity="center"
>             android:textSize="@dimen/label_font_size" />
>         <EditText
>             android:id="@+id/subscriber_id_2of4"
>             android:layout_width="0dp"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_gravity="top"
>             android:layout_weight="45"
>             android:inputType="text"
>             android:maxLength="8"
>             android:textStyle="bold"
>             android:textSize="@dimen/entry_font_size"
>             android:gravity="center"/>
>     </LinearLayout>
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:orientation="horizontal"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_gravity="top"
>         android:weightSum="100">
>         <EditText
>             android:id="@+id/subscriber_id_3of4"
>             android:layout_width="0dp"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_gravity="top"
>             android:layout_weight="45"
>             android:inputType="text"
>             android:maxLength="8"
>             android:textStyle="bold"
>             android:textSize="@dimen/entry_font_size"
>             android:gravity="center"/>
>         <TextView
>             android:layout_width="0dp"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_gravity="top"
>             android:layout_weight="10"
>             android:text="-"
>             android:gravity="center"
>             android:textSize="@dimen/label_font_size" />
>         <EditText
>             android:id="@+id/subscriber_id_4of4"
>             android:layout_width="0dp"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_gravity="top"
>             android:layout_weight="45"
>             android:inputType="text"
>             android:maxLength="8"
>             android:textStyle="bold"
>             android:textSize="@dimen/entry_font_size"
>             android:gravity="center"/>
>     </LinearLayout>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

QUESTIONS:

1. Why isn't the AM / PM spinner appearing in the emulator for the `TimePicker`?
2. Why in the emulator is the layout vertically much longer than in the Design tab in Studio?
3. How do you make a layout in Studio that is robust to varying screen dimensions (i.e., form factors) for different devices?

Comment: In the Design tab in Studio, I think the AM / PM spinner is truncated as a result of limited space in the width.  The way I'm going to resolve this issue is to present the service start / end times as a button, and to present the TimePicker as a popup dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two TimePickers were collectively too wide for my phone screen.  It appears the Design renderer (in Studio) and the UI renderer (in the Emulator) coped with the overreach in different ways -- i.e., the Design tab simply truncated the AM / PM spinner (see my earlier screenshot), while the Emulator left out the AM / PM spinner altogether, and pushed remaining content further down.  This difference accounts for the discrepancies appearing in the rendered outputs.

To resolve, I simply replaced the TimePickers with buttons that surface a TimePickerDialog when activated.  The rendered UI is now identical in both the Emulator and the Design view in Studio.  Here's the Emulator screenshot, for example:

[image]